# Find an expression for $\sin{x} + 2\sin(2x) +3\sin(3x) + ... +n\sin(nx)$

Tags: trigonometric-series

I'm struggling with this problem,

Find an expression for $\sin{x} + 2\sin(2x)  +3\sin(3x) + ... +n\sin(nx)$

The problem states that I have to explicitly show that this series can be expressed as

$$\frac{(n+1)\sin(nx) - n\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin^2(x/2)}$$

For all $ n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R} $

Comment: I'd use $$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

Comment: Using the De Moivre formula, this turns to a geometric series.

Comment: Hint: Use $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and a geometric series.

Comment: use demoivre formula

Comment: If you know the series for cos(nx), taking the derivative will give you the above series. Finding it by scratch isn't as easy.

Comment: @Kaynex I know the series for cos(nx), but why will taking the derivative of the series of cos(nx) give me the series nsin(nx)?

Comment: What is the derivative of $\cos(j x)$ for a natural number $j$?

Comment: @Arthur, I attempted to differentiate the cos(nx) series but I get stuck at a certain point (after using the quotient rule), could you possibly post a solution to the derivative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

This is the imaginary part of 
$$\mathrm e^{ix}+2\,\mathrm e^{2ix}+\dots+n\,\mathrm e^{nix},$$
which is ‘almost’ the derivative of 
$$1+\mathrm e^{ix}+\mathrm e^{2ix}+\dots+\mathrm e^{nix}.$$
The last expression is a geometric series.

**Variant:**
 you may already know these formulæ (which can be obtained in a way similar to the first method):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx=\frac{\sin\dfrac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\dfrac x2}\,\sin\dfrac{nx}{2},\qquad\sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx=\frac{\sin\dfrac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\dfrac x2}\,\cos\dfrac{nx}{2} $$
and differentiate the second of these.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

With $z=e^{ix}$, your sum is the imaginary part of

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kz^k=z\frac{1 - z^n}{(1-z)^2} - nz\frac{z^n}{1-z}=\frac{2z}{(1-z)^2} +\frac{nz}{1-z}.$$

The rest is routine work.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k\sin\left(kx\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{k=1}^n ke^{kix}\right)
$$
using $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.  Now, we can rewrite the sum as a double sum where
$$
\Im\left(\sum_{k=1}^n ke^{kix}\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{j=m}^n e^{jix}\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{m=1}^ne^{mix}\sum_{j=0}^{n-m} e^{jix}\right).
$$
The inner sum is a geometric sum, so this simplifies to
$$
\Im\left(\sum_{m=1}^ne^{mix}\sum_{j=0}^{n-m} e^{jix}\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{m=1}^ne^{mix}\left(\frac{1-e^{(n-m+1)ix}}{1-e^{ix}}\right)\right).
$$
This is, again, geometric (actually two geometric sums), and you can continue the computation.

Comment: I've taken the freedom to adapt the answer to the merged question and improve the indexing of the sums in the process (some of the sums should start at $1$).